# Why hibernate ignoring my updates?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I created abstract generic @MappedSuperclass. This is working fine with select, insert queries. But hibernate don't generate update queries. I don't understand what's wrong with generic class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Cacheable
public abstract class Category<T extends Category> {

  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private T parent;

  private List<T> children;

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  //omitted 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "staticPageCategory")
public class StaticPageCategory extends Category<StaticPageCategory> implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne
  @Override
  public StaticPageCategory getParent() {
    return super.getParent();
  }

  @OrderBy("ordering asc, name asc")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  @Override
  public List<StaticPageCategory> getChildren() {
    return super.getChildren();
  }
}
```

Question is why hibernate ignoring getCurrentSession().update(myCategory);

Comment: Can you post how are you updating your entites and if there is any exception the stackTrace

Comment: In what way she is ignoring, not texting or not picking up your calls. Please let us know by adding stacktrace and what you are trying to do

Comment: I checked log there no exception, no warnings. I also enabled debug level.

Comment: checked sql log. there is no update sql generated.